# How to use Ideone API in WSDL Format

Tags: api, compiler-construction, wsdl

I want to set up my own online compiler. I want to use Ideone Api for this. But its api is available in WSDL format. I tried very hard but could find any tutorial on how to extract data from WSDL. Please tell some way to use Ideone api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a late answer but still may be useful for others. Here a simple example in PHP  with it's native SOAP libray: http://ideone.com/3JBbt

Regretfully my server doesn't support PHP's SOAP library so I have used NuSOAP in the demo, now you have two ways to work with IDE One API.

Here a simple demo: http://rendon.x10.mx/files/ide1example/

And here is the code: http://rendon.x10.mx/files/ide1example.tar.gz

**NOTE:** You need provide your own user and password in ideone.php.

```
  $params = array(
            'user' => $user, // your user
            'pass' => $pass, // your pass
            'sourceCode' => $code,
            'language' => $lang,
            'input' => $input,
            'run' => $run,
            'private' => $private
        );
```

For more info about the functions consult the API document: http://ideone.com/files/ideone-api.pdf

Answer (score 0):

WSDL as name says, it describes functionality or the methods for communicating a webservice ,

As you said you have WSDL, then i would suggest you to create a WebService Client and start using it in your program.
For creating a WebService client, i would suggest you to use some tools such as Ex: http://cxf.apache.org/, they give you nice tools to create WS Clients like WS2js, WS2Java etc., kinda

As u've mentioned Ideone specifically , i'm working on it too, i would suggest you to look at creating a WSclient from WSDL in Netbeans(for this you need to download a plugin JAX-RPC)
or refer to this project http://code.google.com/p/ideone-cli/ , they've a working implementation of ideone WS Client.